# Soft deleted instance is not retrieved by Laravel Resource

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete, laravel-resource

I have two models related to each other with a one-to-one relationship.

Model A belongs to model B and when an instance of model B is returned to the frontend, the [Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources) of the model B includes the data of the modal A like this example.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class B extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'prop1' => $this->prop1,

            'modelA' => $this->model_a,
            // ...
```

### Issue

However, I'm having problems when the Model A instance that would be included in a response is *soft deleted*. I can retrieve the soft deleted model B using `ModelB::withTrashed()->get()`, but the model B resource doesn't include its related soft deleted model A.

I tried "manually" selecting modelA in the following ways, but it didn't work.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class B extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'prop1' => $this->prop1,

            'modelA' => ModelAResource::make($this->resource->modalARelation()->withTrashed()->get()),
            'modelA' => ModelAResource::make($this->modalARelation()->withTrashed()->get()),
            'modelA' => ModelA::withTrashed()->where('model_b', $this->id)->get(),
            // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually simpler, as I just found out.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class B extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'prop1' => $this->prop1,

            'modelA' => $this->modelARelation()->withTrashed()->get()->first(),
            // ...
```